# Force measure to display grand total (as average)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the below measure:

```
VAR VParent =
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE ( Revenue, 'Customer'[Parent], 'Cost'[Business] ),
        [Measure1] > 0
    )

VAR MaxParent = MAXX ( VParent, [Measure1] )

VAR SubT = CALCULATE ( [Measure1], VParent )

VAR VLead =
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE ( Revenue, 'Leads'[No], 'Cost'[Business] ),
        [Measure1] > 0
    )

VAR Max_Leads = MAXX ( VLead, [Measure1] )

VAR SubTotal_Leads = CALCULATE ( [Measure1], VLead )

RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Customer'[Customer] ), DIVIDE ( SubT, MaxParent ),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Customer'[Parent] ), DIVIDE ( SubT, MaxParent ),
        ISINSCOPE ( 'Leads'[Emp] ), DIVIDE ( SubTotal_Leads, Max_Leads ),
        BLANK ()
    )
```

If I select "table" visualization in Power BI, grand total appears BLANK()…

The measure as it is works fine, but I wanted to add a grand total whenever I display it in a table.

I am not sure if it is possible to display a grand total (as an average) of what is displayed.

Comment: I think you declare too much variable in your dax function, mind show some sample data and expected output in excel?

Answer (score 0):

A grand total will not have anything in scope, so the SWITCH function returns a blank, just as specified by your measure.

Comment: True. But, I am to display a GrandTotal, of whatever is displayed... That is; if  'Customer'[Customer] is in scope, I am to display the grand total for that.

Comment: There is no scope for a grand total, so the question would be how are you controlling what scope you're showing in your visual?